# How to resume ModelSim (end step-through) after breakpoint

Tags: breakpoints, modelsim

I am new to ModelSim and was wondering how one resumes simulation after being stopped by a breakpoint. I have a part of my VHDL code that I want to investigate, so I have placed a breakpoint at the beginning of that block of code. However, this part of the code is only entered when a specific event occurs, so once the simulation has been halted once by the breakpoint, I want to be able to resume it, so that it is not stopped again until the breakpoint is encountered again. I assume this is possible since it is a common debugging feature in programming languages and I do not see why it cannot be implemented in an HDL simulator.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer. At the top of the window, along with all the other run buttons, there is a button called ContinueRun. This does what I wanted. The Tcl command "run -continue" can also be used.